# Is it better to add elements to a set or to convert list a into a set?

Tags: python, performance, set, unique

I am creating the logic for a Big Data pipeline which performs aggregations. I need to count the number of unique values for a field, so I have decided to use `set`'s.

I do not know which way of counting the number of unique elements would be better taking into consideration that the number of entries can be a huge number.

I have thought of two ways:

**1. Create an empty `set` and add each entry to it.**

```
myset = set()
for entry in entries:
    myset.add(entry['key'])
uniques = len(myset)
```

This option will have to check whether the value exists on the set each time a new entry arrives. If the number of possible values is small, I think it may be faster.

**2. Create a list, append all entries to it and convert it into a set**

```
mylist = list()
for entry in entries:
    mylist.append(entry['key'])
uniques = len(set(mylist))
```

This option will only search for unique values once, although in a bigger collection. If the number of possible values is huge (e.g: IDs or emails), I think it may be faster.

---

Are my assumptions correct? Is there any way to find unique values which is the best regardless of conditions?

Comment: Why assume when you can `timeit`?

Comment: Use a set comprehension `myset = {entry['key'] for entry in entries}` and let the core developers deal with optimization. If they deem it faster to use some other data structure under the hood, fine. Otherwise, go for the first option. Why waste space for  a huge in-memory list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"This option will only search for unique values once, although in a bigger collection"*? Why would that be faster? Does it have to do with this being a "pipeline"/"aggregation" somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a function to make our list of entries.

```
def make_entries(size):
    return [{'key': random.randint(1, size//2)} for _ in range(size)]
```

We're going to use this to create lists of different sizes and test how fast each approach is.

Approach 1: create an empty set and add to it

```
def add_to_set(entries):
    myset = set()
    for entry in entries:
        myset.add(entry['key'])
    return len(myset)
```

Approach 2: create a list and then use it to create a set

```
def create_from_list(entries):
    mylist = list()
    for entry in entries:
        mylist.append(entry['key'])
    return len(set(mylist))
```

Approach 2a: Use a list comprehension to create the list, then create a set

```
def create_from_list_comprehension(entries):
    return len(set([entry['key'] for entry in entries]))
```

Approach 3: Use a set comprehension ([@schwobaseggl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390182/schwobaseggl)'s suggestion in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68772374/is-it-better-to-add-elements-to-a-set-or-to-convert-list-a-into-a-set/68774917#comment121539602_68772374))

```
def set_comprehension(entries):
    return len({entry['key'] for entry in entries})
```

Next, we can time each of these approaches for different values of `size`.

```
sizes = [10, 50, 100, 500, 1_000, 5_000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000]

times = []

for size in sizes:
    times.append([])
    entries = make_entries(size)
    nrepeat = 1000
    times[-1].append(timeit.timeit('add_to_set(entries)', setup='from __main__ import entries, add_to_set', number=nrepeat) / nrepeat)
    times[-1].append(timeit.timeit('create_from_list(entries)', setup='from __main__ import entries, create_from_list', number=nrepeat) / nrepeat)
    times[-1].append(timeit.timeit('create_from_list_comprehension(entries)', setup='from __main__ import entries, create_from_list_comprehension', number=nrepeat) / nrepeat)
    times[-1].append(timeit.timeit('set_comprehension(entries)', setup='from __main__ import entries, set_comprehension', number=nrepeat) / nrepeat)
```

I ran this on my Win10 laptop using Python 3.7.7, where `print(sys.version)` gives

```
3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Now if we plot `times`, we see that using a set comprehension is consistently faster than all other approaches.

[image]

Between the two approaches you came up with, adding to the set directly is generally faster than creating a list and then creating a set out of that list, but not by much: about 1.2x faster on average.

---

If you're interested, these are the numbers I get for `times`. Columns correspond to the different approaches, and rows are for different sizes.

```
times = [[1.91180001e-06, 2.25380005e-06, 1.43129996e-06, 7.10900058e-07],
       [4.31230001e-06, 6.94569992e-06, 3.65169998e-06, 2.49419990e-06],
       [1.56470999e-05, 1.50408000e-05, 8.06160003e-06, 5.67660003e-06],
       [6.51685999e-05, 7.41121001e-05, 6.79391000e-05, 4.49675000e-05],
       [1.40047500e-04, 1.70246000e-04, 9.80658000e-05, 6.99476000e-05],
       [8.01188900e-04, 1.00142830e-03, 4.92695100e-04, 5.36500400e-04],
       [1.35429690e-03, 1.53512830e-03, 8.99595700e-04, 8.74221300e-04],
       [8.91747430e-03, 1.10454779e-02, 8.46084390e-03, 7.77944500e-03],
       [1.97166152e-02, 1.95640820e-02, 1.17698472e-02, 1.20813099e-02]]
```